# How to use a standalone database in a linux machine?

Tags: php, database, linux, installation

I have a linux machine server, I am able to use php in it. I can only connect to it using a putty command prompt or an FTP program. (basically have limited access).
Is there a way I can use a free database (like mysql)? I'm don't think I can install it on the root folders because of permissions, that's why I was thinking maybe there is a database tool that works as a standalone file, and each database is created as a resource file. That way there is no need for an installation, and you can keep the whole thing in some sub folder in the location where I do have access.

Is this possible?

I am hoping for something like, I download a file, place it on some folder after transferring it through FTP program. Then use php code to create a database and insert/delete records.
And every database created is stored as a file somewhere beside the database tool.

Comment: Ehm, is there a database running or not? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: "a putty command prompt" does not imply limited access.

Comment: @Oliver: i am not sure if there a database, but if there is, i dont want to use that. I am looking to do basic record inserting and querying, kind of like keeping track of user accounts.

Comment: The question is, do you have any access data for a mysql database or not. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use sqlite I think is just what you are looking for.

http://www.sqlite.org/about.html

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to install this and interact with it using php?

Comment: you can also run mysql in standalone mode on a non-standard port as a screened or hupped application under userspace rather than having it run as a daemon under init.d.  Its not a trivial install but its certainly possible.

Comment: @dave: is there a tutorial for this?